# creating a list of figures following APA style 7th edition

Tags: microsoft-word, list

For my thesis, I use APA 7th edition.They request the figures to be presented like this

Figure 1 ( in bold)
double interline

Caption  ( in italic)

When I extract the list of figures from Word I only get
Figure 1..... page number

But I dont get the caption, since the caption is on the line below. How can I do to include in the list of figure the caption that is in the line below?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you can use New Line characters (Shift-Enter) instead of Paragraph Mark characters (Enter). So if you start with

**Figure 1** *Caption*

Then click immediately before *Caption* and press Shift-Enter twice.

When you next update the Table of Figures, you should see that each New Line character is replaced by a space.

Comment: that works! thank you so much!

Comment: @DianaLinda Don't forget to "Accept" the Answer - see e.g. https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers